# Array indices must be positive integers or logical value when read images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

trying to read multi images in matlab in loop so error Array indices must be positive integers or logical values is appear

```
for i=1:12  % we have 16 images we have in or folder
clc;clear;
images ='/home/mohamed/Downloads/Lab6-20200415/Lab6-20200421/Lab6/Lab6/';
jpgfiles=dir(fullfile(images,'\*.jpg*'));
n=numel(jpgfiles(i));
im=jpgfiles(i).name;
im1=imread(fullfile(images,im));
d1 = rg2gray(iml);
imshow(im1);
end
```

Comment: Please provide the exact and complete wording of the error message. Please [edit] your question in the form of a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example demonstrating your problem:

```
for i=1:10
    clear
    jpgfiles=rand(10,1); %some dummy data to replace your actual code
    jpgfiles(i);
end
```

the clear deletes the variable `i` which means `i` is the imaginary unit, not a valid index. Avoid the variable name `i`, it leads to difficult to debug problems. With other variable names, the much clearer error message would have been:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'ix'.

Error in foo (line 4)
    jpgfiles(ix);
```